# TypeError: find() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dummy dataset,

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris','Cumings, Mrs.John','Heikkinen, Miss. Lainia', 'Futerelle, Mrs. Jacques Health', 'Allen, Mr. William Henry'], columns=['Names'])
```

which has head of

```
     Names
0   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
1   Cumings, Mrs.John
2   Heikkinen, Miss. Lainia
3   Futerelle, Mrs. Jacques Health
4   Allen, Mr. William Henry
```

I am trying to solve a dummy problem where I am finding index of first column occurring ',' by this code

```py
df['Names'].apply(str.find(','))
```

but it is giving following error.

```py
TypeError: find() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Can I know why is this giving this error even I am providing the argument?

Comment: submitted answers are quite detailed, the syntex you are using to get your string is off. It could be something like this  name_string = df['Names'][0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two main issues:

1. You are trying to call `find` in a static way (from the `str` class instead of an instance), in which case it is expecting 2 arguments (the string and the substring).
2. `.apply` accepts a function and you given it an integer (the assumed output of `str.find`).

Pandas provides an [`str` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) that exposes the most common `str` methods and applies them in vectorized way:

```
print(df.Names.str.find(','))
```

outputs

```
0    6
1    7
2    9
3    9
4    5
Name: Names, dtype: int64
```

You could still use Python's `str.find`, but you'd have to create a custom lambda:

```
print(df.Names.apply(lambda string: string.find(',')))
```

Also outputs

```
0    6
1    7
2    9
3    9
4    5
Name: Names, dtype: int64
```

But using the `str` accessor (or any other available accessor, or pandas method) will almost always be more efficient than a lambda passed to `.apply`.

Of course, you can reassign the result back to a new column in both cases:

```
df['First Comma Index'] = df.Names.str.find(',')
df['First Comma Index'] = df.Names.apply(lambda string: string.find(','))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access string methods for a column or Series directly using `df['Names'].str`. This'll let you do `df['Names'].str.find(",")`.

You're getting the error because "str" here is just the class, not any particular string, so it's expecting an underlying string in which to look and doesn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You may loop to get the result as follows -

**Code -**

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    string = df['Names'][i]
    df['Index'][i] = string.find(',',0,len(string))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: No, please don't loop over a dataframe. There is almost always a (much) faster vectorized solution. Also, why bothering passing `0,len(string)` to `.find`? these are the default values.

Comment: I used loop to get a separate column with the indices. Any O(1) way to do this ?

Comment: Any vectorized solution, like the one in my answer, will be faster than looping in Python. Not O(1), but a much faster O(n) (since it is executed in C level)

Comment: Okay I'll look to that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully You can Apply This Method :

```
df["Finds"] = df["Names"].str.find(",")
```

This Will Give You The Result As Follows :

```
    Names                            Finds
0   Braund, Mr. Owen Harris          6
1   Cumings, Mrs.John                7
2   Heikkinen, Miss. Lainia          9
3   Futerelle, Mrs. Jacques Health   9
4   Allen, Mr. William Henry         5
```

I Hope This Will Help You.