# getting this error called TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, count, typeerror

This program calculates the number of letters in a str input. If the user types 'ns' it prints the number
of letters without the spaces

**This is the code**

```
name = input('Enter a sentence to calculate the number of letters: \n')
counter = str(len(name))


print(counter, ": with spaces.")
spaces = input("Type 'ns' to calculate the letters without the spaces \n")
counter_without_spaces = str(str.count(name))
if spaces == 'ns':
    print(counter_without_spaces)



input()
```

**This is the error in the terminal**

```
TypeError: count() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what im doing wrong and teach me the correct one? 

Comment: Almost duplicate of [python - TypeError: find() takes at least 1 argument (0 given) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625633/typeerror-find-takes-at-least-1-argument-0-given) ; [Python String Replace Error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901914/python-string-replace-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one of the things you can do:

```
name = input('Enter a sentence to calculate the number of letters: \n')
counter = str(len(name))


print(counter, ": with spaces.")
spaces = input("Type 'ns' to calculate the letters without the spaces \n")
counter_without_spaces = str(name.count(" "))
if spaces == 'ns':
    print(str(int(counter) - int(counter_without_spaces)))
```

Another Way:

```
name = input('Enter a sentence to calculate the number of letters: \n')
counter = str(len(name))
print(counter, ": with spaces.")
spaces = input("Type 'ns' to calculate the letters without the spaces \n")
if spaces == 'ns':
  print(str(len(name)-name.count(" ")))
```

Output:

```
Enter a sentence to calculate the number of letters: 
abc def
7 : with spaces.
Type 'ns' to calculate the letters without the spaces 
ns
6
```

**About `count()`:**

The `string count()` method returns the number of occurrences of a substring in the given string.

In simple words, `count()` method searches the substring in the given string and returns how many times the substring is present in it.

Comment: so, it removes the " " from the str and counts the letters itself, thanks a lot, you really helped me

Comment: Small nit: you don't need the explicit use of `str` here, `print` is more than happy to `print` out the integer without the conversion to a string

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
answer = input("with space or without  yes/no")
word = input("enter word : ")
if str(answer) == "no":
    print(len(word))
else:

    print(len(word.replace(" ", "")))
```

Comment: i have seen this before, but how can it count the number of letters without spaces?

Comment: That's what this does: it removes the spaces, and returns the length of the resulting string.

Comment: the code will remove the spaces then cout for you exact lenth that what mean .replace(" ","")

Comment: Tip for next time: add explanations of code as part of your answer, rather than as follow-up comments.

Answer (score 0):

You failed to tell it what to count.  You called `count` through the class, which means you have to give it both the string and the character you want to count within that string.  When it got to the *actual* `count` function, it had already converted your call into its canonical form:

```
name.count()
```

... where you're missing the required argument.

You need to return to the materials on strings and the `count` method in particular.  Your program logic shows that you aren't clear on how it works.  You need to count the spaces and subtract that from the total string length ... both of which you now know how to do.